# MySQL: reorder rows from file association

Tags: mysql

A MySQL photo gallery script requires that I provide the display order of my gallery by pairing each image title to a number representing the desired order.

---

I have a list of correctly ordered data called `pairs_list.txt` that looks like this:

```
#   title          correct data in list
--  -------
1   kmmal
2   bub14
3   ili2
4   sver2
5   ell5
6   ello1
...
```

So, the `kimmals` image will be displayed first, then the `bub14` image, etc.

---

My MySQL table called `title_order` has the same titles above, but they are not paired with the right numbers:

```
#   title          bad data in MySQL
--  -------
14  kmmal
100 bub14
31  ili2
47  sver2
32  ell5
1   ello1
...
```

---

How can I make a MySQL script that will look at the correct number-title pairings from `pairs_list.txt` and go through each row of `title_order`, replacing each row with the correct number? In other words, how can I make the order of the MySQL table look like that of the text file?

In pseudo-code, it might look like something like this:

1. Get MySQL row title
2. Search `pair_list.txt` for this title
3. Get the correct number-title pair in list
4. Replace the MySQL number with the correct number
5. Repeat for all rows

Thank you for any help!

Comment: [What have you tried](http://mattgemmell.com/2008/12/08/what-have-you-tried/)?

Comment: Do you need any of the current data in the table?  If not it would be easier to just `delete from title_order` and then insert as CSV.

Comment: @ghoti I haven't tried anything much because I really have no idea on how to solve this. I've looked at other sources online, but they don't talk about easily reordering MySQL tables based on files. Although, I guess you I could do this in PHP...

Comment: @KenThompson Yes, I have more data in the table like description and filename, so I can't delete the table.

Comment: How long is the list?  It still might be easiest to just mysqldump the table, change the # column, and import it back.

Comment: @KenThompson It's about 200 rows long.

Comment: In that case if it's just a one time thing I would do (if I were you) `mysqldump pairs_list > somefile.txt` then edit the file then do `mysql < somefile.txt` (make sure there is a drop table in the mysqldump so that you will only be left with the original rows).  If it's recurring try tartar's solutions or write an external script.

Answer (score 1):

if this is not a one time task but will be frequently called function, then maybe you can have the following scenario:

1. create a temp table, insert all the values from pairs_list.txt into this temp table using mysql [load data infile](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/load-data.html) function.
2. create a procedure (or a insert trigger maybe?) on that temp table which would update your main table according to whatever inserted.
3. in that procedure (or a insert trigger), I would have a cursor getting all values from temp table and for each value from that cursor update the selected title on your main table.
4. delete all from that temp table

Comment: In that scenario, your program should execute a load data command populated with file name then should call the procedure name with maybe a parameter. It is also important if multiple user will do the same thing at the same time. Then, probably it is necessary to have a transaction id or user name provided to procedure call.

Comment: Thanks tartar. I'll try to make a function like this.

Answer (score 1):

I'd suggest you to do this simple way -

**1** Remove all primary and unique keys from the `title_order` table, and create unique index (or primary key) on `title` field -

```
ALTER TABLE title_order
  ADD UNIQUE INDEX UK_title_order_title (title);
```

**2** Use LOAD DATA INFILE with REPLACE option to load data from the file and replace  -

```
LOAD DATA INFILE 'pairs_list.txt'
    REPLACE
    INTO TABLE title_order
    FIELDS TERMINATED BY '  '
    LINES TERMINATED BY '\r\n'
    IGNORE 2 LINES
    (@col1, @col2)
    SET order_number_field = @col1, title = TRIM(@col2);
```

...specify properties you need in LOAD DATA INFILE command.